# I accidentally deleted /etc/nginx, reinstalling nginx won't recover it

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apt

I'm on Ubuntu and I was trying to recover the original settings of `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` when I accidentally deleted the entire folder. Uninstalling and reinstalling nginx through `apt-get` won't recreate the original folders.
What can I do to recover them?

Comment: Can't you simply download the package, extract it and find the configuration file you need? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Force the reinstall of the default config files with the `--force-confmiss` option of `dpkg`.

Looks like the packaging layout for nginx changed in 11.04.  If you're on 10.10 or older:

```
sudo dpkg --force-confmiss -i /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_*.deb
```

Or 11.04 and newer:

```
sudo dpkg --force-confmiss -i /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_*.deb
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work (beware that this uninstalls nginx completely):

```
apt-get purge nginx nginx-common nginx-full
```

and then

```
apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: This worked for me but you lose all of other configuration files with nginx. There should be a way to just re-create default file in sites-available.

Answer (score 3):

check for the deb package in your ubuntu system [your version of deb file may be different]

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_0.8.54-4_all.deb
```

open it using archive manager.
Inside the archive check for folder /etc/nginx

This is the default nginx installation cfg folder. You can copy from here to /etc .

Answer (score 2):

Don't just apt-get remove it, this will leave configurations behind. apt-get purge it, and any unused dependency. You can check inatallation status by grepping dpkg -l output